# Unable to open file with Finder via Apple Script

Tags: finder, applescript, calendar, ical

I have been using an Apple Script that recently stopped working (on macOS 12.4-6). Here is a minimal piece of code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open "Macintosh HD:Users:me:cal.ics"
end tell
```

This used to open up the file in Calendar with a few dialog boxes asking how I want to import the calendar (and this is still what happens if I double-click the file in Finder, or if I run `$ open cal.ics` in the terminal). Now however, when I run the Apple Script above, nothing happens in Calendar. Weirdly though, the `Date last opened` property of `cal.ics` updates to the time the Apple Script is run.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Or an alternative that's not too complex (I can't seem to get Calendar itself to open or import this file via Apple Script). In the worst case, I could tell Terminal to run `$ open cal.ics`, but I'd like to try to keep the script simple.

Edit: I also want to add that if I run the same script as above, but with files of other types (like `.txt`, `.pdf`, etc), there is no problem.

Comment: What if you tell Calendar to open it?

Comment: @benwiggy If I run exactly the script above with `Finder` replaced by `Calendar`, I get `error "Calendar got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000`.